# click on button doesn't do anythng

Tags: android

When I click my button3, it should print out a text in the console. However, it does not do anything at all.  I also tried making a toast but that also didn't work. Literally nothing happens.

I just edited the whole post.
I've removed the showInfo() from onClick().
I've now done so that when I click on the button (button3), then it'll run the method showInfo().

However, absolutely nothing happens in the console. It doesn't print anything out.

```
package com.KSB.exam.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.KSB.exam.R;
import com.KSB.exam.model.Car;
import com.KSB.exam.sql.DatabaseHelper;
import com.KSB.exam.sql.DatabaseHelperCar;

public class CarRegActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
Button cancel;
private DatabaseHelperCar databaseHelper;
private final AppCompatActivity activity = CarRegActivity.this;

Spinner carModelspinner;
Spinner carEnergyspinner;
Spinner carTypeSpinner;
Spinner yearSpinner;
Spinner carColorspinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_reg);

    String[] carModel = {"Toyota", "Audi", "BMW", "Volvo", "KIA", "Ford"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> carModelArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carModel);
    carModelspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CarModelspinner);
    carModelspinner.setAdapter(carModelArrayAdapter);

    String[] carEnergy = {"Diesel", "Petrol", "Octen", "Benzin"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> carEnergyArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carEnergy);
    carEnergyspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCarEnergy);
    carEnergyspinner.setAdapter(carEnergyArrayAdapter);

    String[] carType = {"Personal Car", "Bus", "Mini Bus", "Truck"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> carTypeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carType);
    carTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCarType);
    carTypeSpinner.setAdapter(carTypeArrayAdapter);

    String[] year = {"1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008",
            "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> yearArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, year);
    yearSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
    yearSpinner.setAdapter(yearArrayAdapter);


    String[] carColor = {"RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "BLACK", "WHITE", "SILVER", "OTHER"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> carColorArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carColor);
    carColorspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerColor);
    carColorspinner.setAdapter(carColorArrayAdapter);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelperCar(activity);


    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(CarRegActivity.this, UsersListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showInfo();

        }
    });
}

public void ShowMain(View v)
{
    String button_text;
    button_text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    if (button_text.equals("Cancel"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public void submitToDB(View v)
{
    String button_text;
    button_text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    if (button_text.equals("Submit"))
    {

        Car car = new Car();


        final EditText licensePlate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        String licensePlateStr = licensePlate.getText().toString();

        final EditText cModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
        String cModelStr = cModel.getText().toString();

        final EditText totalKM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText17);
        String totalKMStr = totalKM.getText().toString();

        final EditText priceDKK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText18);
        String priceDKKStr = priceDKK.getText().toString();

        final EditText userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String userIDStr = userID.getText().toString();


        car.setLicensePlate(licensePlateStr);
        car.setCarmodel(cModelStr);
        car.setTypeOfGas(carEnergyspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        car.setColor(carColorspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        car.setTypeOfVehicle(carTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        car.setYear(yearSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        car.setTotalKM(totalKMStr);
        car.setPrice(priceDKKStr);
        car.setUserID(userIDStr);


        databaseHelper.addCar(car);
    }
}
public void showInfo()
{

    System.out.println("jjjjjjj im a click on button3! ");


//        Context context = getApplicationContext();
//        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
//        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
//
//        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
//        toast.show();


}



}
```

And the .xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="CarID"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="CarID"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_car_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            tools:text="CarID"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Licenseplate"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Licenseplate"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_license_Plate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Car Model"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Car Model"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_car_model"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Type of gas"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Type of gas"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_type_of_gas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Color"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Color"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Car Type"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Car Type"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_type_of_vehicle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Year"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Year"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_year"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Total KM"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Total KM"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_total_km"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="Price"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="SellerID"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            tools:text="SellerID"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_user_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/hint_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What class is the `showInfo` method in?

Comment: It's in a class called CarRegActivity.java.

I tried changing it to showInfo(CarRegActivity) but that didn't work either, @SuperStormer.

Comment: Putting a Log message or a Toast directly inside the Click Listener doesn't do anything either?

Comment: @SammyT, nope ... and it's driving me crazy :/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide View for the showInfo() method.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  showInfo();
            }
}
```

And the showInfo() will get called whenever Button button gets clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have done in your Activity but you can do this;

//find your Button and define it

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3)
```

//set OnClick for Your button

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //here you can do what you want
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sadly it did not. It didn't print out anything - but at least my application is not crashing any longer.

I added the full code in the main post in case you wanted to look at it :)

Comment: just put a toast in your onClickListener to see the result,

Comment: It didn't work. It doesn't do anything at all, @Meikiem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Button clicks fine ! I have run your code Like this

MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Button cancel;
    //private DatabaseHelperCar databaseHelper;
    private final AppCompatActivity activity = MainActivity.this;

    Spinner carModelspinner;
    Spinner carEnergyspinner;
    Spinner carTypeSpinner;
    Spinner yearSpinner;
    Spinner carColorspinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] carModel = {"Toyota", "Audi", "BMW", "Volvo", "KIA", "Ford"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> carModelArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carModel);
        //carModelspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CarModelspinner);
        //carModelspinner.setAdapter(carModelArrayAdapter);

        String[] carEnergy = {"Diesel", "Petrol", "Octen", "Benzin"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> carEnergyArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carEnergy);
        //carEnergyspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCarEnergy);
        //carEnergyspinner.setAdapter(carEnergyArrayAdapter);

        String[] carType = {"Personal Car", "Bus", "Mini Bus", "Truck"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> carTypeArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carType);
        //carTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCarType);
        //carTypeSpinner.setAdapter(carTypeArrayAdapter);

        String[] year = {"1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008",
                "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> yearArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, year);
        //yearSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
       // yearSpinner.setAdapter(yearArrayAdapter);


        String[] carColor = {"RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "BLACK", "WHITE", "SILVER", "OTHER"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> carColorArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, carColor);
        //carColorspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerColor);
        //carColorspinner.setAdapter(carColorArrayAdapter);

       /* databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelperCar(activity);


        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(CarRegActivity.this, UsersListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });*/

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showInfo();

            }
        });
    }

    public void ShowMain(View v)
    {
        String button_text;
        button_text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
        if (button_text.equals("Cancel"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void submitToDB(View v)
    {
        String button_text;
        button_text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
        if (button_text.equals("Submit"))
        {

           /* Car car = new Car();


            final EditText licensePlate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
            String licensePlateStr = licensePlate.getText().toString();

            final EditText cModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
            String cModelStr = cModel.getText().toString();

            final EditText totalKM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText17);
            String totalKMStr = totalKM.getText().toString();

            final EditText priceDKK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText18);
            String priceDKKStr = priceDKK.getText().toString();

            final EditText userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String userIDStr = userID.getText().toString();


            car.setLicensePlate(licensePlateStr);
            car.setCarmodel(cModelStr);
            car.setTypeOfGas(carEnergyspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            car.setColor(carColorspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            car.setTypeOfVehicle(carTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            car.setYear(yearSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            car.setTotalKM(totalKMStr);
            car.setPrice(priceDKKStr);
            car.setUserID(userIDStr);


            databaseHelper.addCar(car);*/
        }
    }
    public void showInfo()
    {

        System.out.println("jjjjjjj im a click on button3! ");


//        Context context = getApplicationContext();
//        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
//        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
//
//        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
//        toast.show();


    }
```

And activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.paramatrix.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="CarID"

                tools:text="CarID"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_car_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                tools:text="CarID"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Licenseplate"

                tools:text="Licenseplate"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_license_Plate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Car Model"

                tools:text="Car Model"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_car_model"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Type of gas"

                tools:text="Type of gas"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_type_of_gas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Color"

                tools:text="Color"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_color"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Car Type"

                tools:text="Car Type"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_type_of_vehicle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Year"

                tools:text="Year"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_year"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Total KM"

                tools:text="Total KM"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_total_km"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Price"

                tools:text="Price"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="SellerID"

                tools:text="SellerID"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_user_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="  hint_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

With some changes and comments !